# I can't read long distance text with pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr

[image]

I have this image and I want to read the text on it but pytesseract returns blank

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import ndimage
import easyocr
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('cikti.jpg')
scale_percent = 220 # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
angles = []
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 90)
for [[x1, y1, x2, y2]] in lines:
    #cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3)
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
    if(angle != 0):
        angles.append(angle)
    
    
    print(angles)
median_angle = np.median(angles)
img = ndimage.rotate(img, median_angle)
print(median_angle)
filiter = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
                    [-1,9,-1],
                    [-1,-1,-1]])

cv2.imshow('filitird', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
reader = easyocr.Reader(['tr'])
ocr_result = reader.readtext(img,)
print(ocr_result)


cv2.imshow('result', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

here is the code i wrote

It may be because of the long distance, but enlarging the picture did not solve my problem.
what should I do

Comment: by 'remote' do you just mean 'from a distance'?  Prob. best rewording if so, my first thought was 'over some kind of network connection'

Comment: Could you explain the network connection? deep learning model?

Comment: I just meant I found 'remote' misleading.  You're *not* using a network connection, so it's moot.   Nice to have the imag in a question like this btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import easyocr

img = cv.imread('result.png',0)
th2 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 29, 10);
cv.imshow("ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C", th2)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()  

reader = easyocr.Reader(['tr'])
ocr_result = reader.readtext(th2,)
print(ocr_result)
```

it worked like this
Image befor ocr : [image]

Result : [image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able successfully to read this image with tesseract by doing the following:

- cropping out the pink border
- reducing to grayscale (binarising)
- running tesseract with `--psm 8` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071353/tesseract-empty-page) )

I don't know if the cropping is necessary, but I couldn't get any output at all with any page segregation mode before binarising.

I did the processing manually here, but you will likely want to automate it.  A good trick for setting thresholds is to look at the standard deviation of the image in question and use that to scale your thresholds, rather than picking some absolute value and having it fail on you.

Here's the image I got working:

[image: working image]

And the run:

```sh
$ tesseract img3.png img3 --psm 8 txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
$ cat img3.txt
47 F02 43
```

I've not tried with pytesseract, but you should be able to set the same thing.

Easy ocr was able to read the image immediately, albeit inaccurately, when I tried with the [web service](https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/)

### Update: grayscaling

This is a whole subject in itself. You might want to start with [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) from the opencv docs.  There are basically two approaches--trying properly to binarise the image (convert it to two colour pixels, on or off) and just grayscaling it.  Somewhere inbetween is 'posterising', where you reduce the number of tones (binarising is a special case of posterising, where the number of tones is 2).  I normally handle grayscaling with the inbuilt function in PIL (pillow); I've had good result with a quick-and-dirty sort-of binarisation algorithm where I first normalise the brightness and contrast of an image and then apply a skewing function like

```py
def filter_point(point: int) -> int:
    if point < THRESH:
        return round(point/1.2)
    else:
        return round(point *2)
```

This drives *most* pixels to fully white/black but leaves some intermediate values in place.  It's a poor solution in that it depends on three magic numbers, but in my application (preparing scanned pdfs for human reading) I got better results than with automated thresholding or posterisation.

Thus sadly the answer is going to be 'play with it'.  I'd suggest you start out with an image editor and see what the bare minimum you can do to the image to get tesseract to work is---perhaps just grayscaling (which you do earlier in the code anyway) will be enough; do you need to crop it, etc. Not drawing that pink box is going to help. I provided a very crude example filter to demonstrate that pixels are just numbers and you can do your image processing that way, but you are *much* better off using built in methods if you possibly can.

Comment: how can i change the picture to gray in this tone

Comment: @HAN-007 see updates.  Note that you *already* make a gray image earlier